# Backspace keyboard shortcut for GTK+

Tags: configuration, shortcut-keys, gtk, thunar

I am using Xubuntu and I am looking for a way to bind the backspace key with navigating to the parent directory of the current directory.

I read in the [Thunar documentation FAQ](http://thunar.xfce.org/documentation/C/faq.html) (at the bottom) that Thunar shortcuts are standard GTK+ keyboard shortcuts, meaning that there are two ways of setting a keyboard shortcut for "open parent":

1. Hovering over the open parent menu option with the mouse pointer and pressing the keyboard shortcut (after enabling the Editable menu accelerators option in settings)
2. Editing $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/Thunar/accels.scm

The first method didn't work because pressing backspace removes any keyboard shortcut assigned to the option instead of assigning backspace to the option.

The second also didn't work but I don't know why. Perhaps the backspace key should be written differently. This is how I tried it:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-parent" "<Backspace>")
```